# Moving data from SQL Server to MYSQL for a PHP application

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm planning a PHP based application and am hoping to get some advice. Here's the background:

The application will be getting some data from multiple MS SQL Server 2008 databases  which are on one remote server (about 50 databases, looking at about 200,000 records across these per day). This data will then need to have various calculations run against each record, and the results displayed to the end user via a web browser.

I'll only have read-only access to the MS SQL Server 2008, and because of this together with the fact that it's a remote server, I was thinking of putting the data into one or more local MySQL databases (which I have root access to) which I can do the calculations within and the web application can query directly.

My question is this:

In terms of performance, what would be the best way to handle the data transfer process? Should I:

1. Use PHP to pull out the data from MS SQL 2008 and drop it into MySQL, perhaps using a PDO connection
2. Use Linked Servers to do this? (and if so can I do this with read-only access to the MSSQL server
3. Another method I've not thought of...

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Do you have access to this infrastructure already? The answer to this depends so much on your specific case, the best answer is to try it. Try without MySQL first, as that adds complexity you _might_ not need. Also, consider doing the calculations remotely (view? stored procedure?) and displaying the results of that - it may result in significantly less data travelling down the wire.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I don't have access to the infrastructure yet unfortunately so can't try it out until next week. I agree it would be best to do as much of the calculations as possible on the databases themselves via stored procedures/views; however I'm only going to have read-only access to these databases which is why I need to move it there.

Comment: I hear you that it is read-only, but without knowing the circumstances, it _might_ be that you can ask the administrator of that system to install a view for you, especially if it helps solve a mutual goal. Whether something is "read-only" can be a political problem as well as a technical one. What is the nature of the ownership of that remote server?

Comment: Of course, if it is absolutely read-only, and there is no chance of setting up anything on the remote side, some sort of sync routine will be necessary to your side. Do you have "last updated" columns on all large tables? Small tables can be copied in their entirety every time, large ones by their last updated timestamps.

Comment: Ownership of the remote server is by the client who has requested the work, however the databases are part of a third-party system. If my system involves more than read-only access to those databases, it puts their support package with the third party at risk, therefore it has to be read only.

Comment: I don't need to copy all the data from the MSSQL databases, just a subset of it which I agree would be nicer to get from a specially-created-view but I don't think that's going to be possible. In answer to your other question - they don't have "last updated" columns on all large tables.

Comment: Sounds like you'd need to copy the whole subset, in that case, for every daily update (at least for every table that does not have a last-updated column). If you can put up with a staleness of up to one day, that sounds doable, so long as your connection between the two is of an acceptable speed.

Comment: yeah, the main issue is whether to do it via php & pdo or use linked servers, or is there a better way considering the read-only restriction...